# Access to Ext JS components with window.document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

Is it possible to get access to an Ext JS component with window.document.getElementById ?
That's instead of using Ext.getCmp.

Comment: Why you do not want to use `getCmp`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you will get the native object without ExtJS wrapper.

Comment: Would I be able to access into an object's data? For example, get a panel's title, get the current active tab in a panel, etc?

Comment: Generally yes, you will get an instance of HTMLElement. If active tab has some specific css class then you can check it, if you know the Id of panel's title element you can get it's text, but it will be not the Ext JS api. It will be "native" DOM operations, you can just get panel.title, you have to find the exact title dom element and get it's innterText property

Comment: Thanks. But what is the ID I should use? Is it the same ID used in the Ext JS api. when the component is defined? (The "id:" field)

Comment: As i remember - yes, look at the markup using browser dev tools (F12 key, or left mouse over element - view/code(inspect element)).

Answer (score 0):

It's actually rather trivial to look up a Component by the element; every Component has a main element with the `id` attribute matching the Component's `id`. So we can do like this:

```
function findComponentByElement(node) {
    var topmost = document.body,
        target = node,
        cmp;

    while (target && target.nodeType === 1 && target !== topmost) {
        cmp = Ext.getCmp(target.id);

        if (cmp) {
            return cmp;
        }

        target = target.parentNode;
    }

    return null;
}

var node, cmp;

node = document.getElementById('foo');
cmp  = findComponentByElement(node);
```

If you have an Ext.Element instance instead of a bare HTMLElement, just pass its DOM pointer instead:

```
var el, cmp;

el  = Ext.Element.getActiveElement(); // Currently focused element
cmp = findComponentByElement(el.dom);
```

Oh, and just for completeness' sake, here's how to get an Ext.Element wrapper for an HTMLElement:

```
var node, el;

node = document.getElementById('bar');
el   = new Ext.Element(node);
```